# How go get max value of a unique id column using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I write this in the simplest way using LINQ?

```
SELECT        MAX(Game_id) AS MaxValue
FROM          Dim_Game
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `context.Dim_Games.Max(g => g.Game_id);`

Comment: I get: `'Project.Models.Dim_Game' does not contain a definition for 'Max'`

Comment: What is the name of the EF entity container that corresponds to `Dim_Game` table in the database?

Comment: @JFB Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs file?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You were thinking the correct thing ;)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549271.aspx  Was my mistake...

Comment: If your column is not nullable and result  of you query can be  empty, see my answer below [How go get max value of a unique id column using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38396527)

Answer (score 1):

If your column is not nullable and result  of you query is  empty, you will receive the error

> "The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type."

To avoid the error you should cast column to nullable and result coalesce with 0.

```
int max=(surveys.Max(g =>( int?)g.SurveyID) ?? 0);
```

See more details in [The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null/6864376#6864376)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a stored procedure like that :

```
 select ident_current('table_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code, if identity increment is on

```html
Convert.ToInt32(_entities.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table') + IDENT_INCR('table')", new object[0]).FirstOrDefault())
```