# Checking null in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

This is my query:

```
var entityMerchantVisit =
     from e in context.MerchantCustomerVisit
     where e.CustomerId == currentCustGuid
     group e by  
           new { e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault().CityId } into mcvGroup
     orderby mcvGroup.Count() descending
     select mcvGroup;
```

I'm getting error

> "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null" when **e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault().CityId** is null.

How do I check if it's null before hand. I would like to assign it as `(int) 0` , if it is null.

Comment: FYI, it's considered good form here to mark the most helpful answer as accepted.  If your question has been answered, please do so!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this could work:

```
var entityMerchantVisit =
     from e in context.MerchantCustomerVisit
     where e.CustomerId == currentCustGuid
     group e by  
           new { e.Merchant.Locations.FirstorDefault() != null 
                  ? e.Merchant.Locations.First().CityId : 0
               } into mcvGroup
     orderby mcvGroup.Count() descending
     select mcvGroup;
```

---

Based on your comment you could maybe try the following (note the parenthesis) :

```
     group e by  
           new { CityID = ((int)e.Merchant.Locations.FirstorDefault() != null 
                  ? e.Merchant.Locations.First().CityId : 0)
               } into mcvGroup
     orderby mcvGroup.Count() descending
```

Comment: `.First()` will not return `null`, it will thrown an exception if there is no item.. You should amend this to `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @AlastairPitts ah! whoops, typed this too quickly. Fixed.

Comment: I tried this 

group e by new { e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault().CityId == null ? e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault().CityId : 0 } into mcvGroup

but it says invalid anonymous type member declarator , what does it means ?

Comment: Ok another way of doing this is , how do I check the result of "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null" . It is not an exception and not actually null . Simply said , how do I check var entityMerchantVisit  when there is this case .

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `let` syntax to bind `e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault()` to a range variable, and then check that for null.  This lets you conveniently identify merchants without locations, and gives you a concise ternary-operator expression to boot.

```
var entityMerchantVisit =
     from e in context.MerchantCustomerVisit
     where e.CustomerId == currentCustGuid
     let location = e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault()
     group e by  
           new { CityId = (location == null ? 0 : location.CityId) } into mcvGroup
     orderby mcvGroup.Count() descending
     select mcvGroup;
```

Comment: nice use of `let` and remembering to add the `CityId` property name to the anonymous type. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use the null coalescing operator (??)

```
var entityMerchantVisit =
 from e in context.MerchantCustomerVisit
 where e.CustomerId == currentCustGuid
 group e by  
       new { (e.Merchant.Locations.FirstOrDefault().CityId ?? 0) } into mcvGroup
 orderby mcvGroup.Count() descending
 select mcvGroup;
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything. The reason for the `NullReferenceException` is that the OP is trying to access the `CityId` off a `null` `Location`. Your code will throw exactly the same exception.

Comment: Where do you see a NullReferenceException? He's not getting an exception. See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null.

Comment: My apologies. I was not aware of how the LINQ-to-SQL interpreter thingo deals with the null coalescing operator. I tried to remove the -1 but the damn thing won't let me :(

Comment: same , getting " invalid anonymous type member declarator" with this

Comment: Ok another way of doing this is , how do I check the result of "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null" . It is not an exception and not actually null . Simply said , how do I check var entityMerchantVisit when there is this case

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `Nullable<int>` expression:

```
var entityMerchantVisit =
    from e in context.MerchantCustomerVisit
    where e.CustomerId == currentCustGuid
    group e by new {
        CityId = e.Merchant.Locations.Any() ? 
            e.Merchant.Locations.First().CityId
            : default(int?)
    } into mcvGroup
    orderby mcvGroup.Count() descending
    select mcvGroup;
```

Comment: By grouping-by an `int?` type, the complete range of values of `CityId` - from `Int32.MinValue` to `Int32.MaxValue` is retained.