# The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: linq

I am having a problem with this query it's throwing an error.

```
var TotalToDatePayable = (  from ori in db.GetAll<WMPORI>()
                           where ori.CTMSysID == ctmSysId
                          select ori.ExB4Taxes).Sum();
```

I tried below code from [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null) but that did not solve my problem:

```
 var TotalToDatePayable = (Decimal?)(  from ori in db.GetAll<WMPORI>()
                                      where ori.CTMSysID == ctmSysId
                                     select ori.ExB4Taxes).Sum()) ?? 0;
```

Comment: This is working:   var TotalToDatePayable = (from ori in db.GetAll<WMPORI>()
                                          where ori.CTMSysID == ctmSysId
                                          select ori.ExB4Taxes).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I thought that kind of indenting was exclusive to Objective C. Now I'm sad.

Comment: @Rawling 9: this kind of indentation is typical in SQL (which Linq emulates in the question) as well. That was the reason for me to add spaces.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to cast `ori.ExB4Taxes` to `decimal?` inside the query.

```
var TotalToDatePayable = (from ori in db.GetAll<WMPORI>()
                          where ori.CTMSysID == ctmSysId
                          select (Decimal?) ori.ExB4Taxes).Sum() ?? 0;
```

Comment: You only need to add 1 more Parentheses at the beginning of query other than that its working perfect. Thanks.