# The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**CODE:**

```
double cafeSales = db.InvoiceLines
    .Where(x =>
        x.UserId == user.UserId &&
        x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
        x.DateCharged <= dateEnd)
    .Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);
```

**ERROR:**

The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

**WHAT I HAVE SEEN ALREADY:**

[The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null)

[The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819475/the-cast-to-value-type-decimal-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null)

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

```
double cafeSales = db.InvoiceLines
    .Where(x =>
        x.UserId == user.UserId &&
        x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
        x.DateCharged <= dateEnd)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);
```

And:

```
double? cafeSales = db.InvoiceLines
    .Where(x =>
        x.UserId == user.UserId &&
        x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
        x.DateCharged <= dateEnd)
    .Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);
```

Neither of these work. I know the cause of the problem is that there are no rows in that table for the UserId I am passing in. In that case, I would prefer Sum() just returned a 0 to me. Any ideas?

Comment: You should mark as answer from any below solutions which is most suitable and efficient.

Comment: You should accept an answer from below for others to rely on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null)

Answer (score 72):

Best Solution

```
double cafeSales = db.InvoiceLines
                     .Where(x =>
                                x.UserId == user.UserId &&
                                x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
                                x.DateCharged <= dateEnd)
                     .Sum(x => (double?)(x.Quantity * x.Price)) ?? 0;
```

Comment: Great! That the way to go.

Comment: Worked brilliantly !! Thanks @jitendra

Answer (score 8):

You can check if the collection has any correct results.

```
double? cafeSales = null;
var invoices = db.InvoiceLines
    .Where(x =>
        x.UserId == user.UserId &&
        x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
        x.DateCharged <= dateEnd
    )
    .Where(x => x.Quantity != null && x.Price != null);
if (invoices.Any()) {
    cafeSales = invoices.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);
}
```

Comment: I did come up with something similar myself just now, but I was hoping there'd be a cleaner way to do it.. in one statement.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that 2 queries get send to the db, first for the Any() to see if there are any records and then the second record to do the actual sum().

Comment: There are no 2 queries but only one. The `Where` method does not actually make a query but prepares one and the call to `Any` makes the real db-query. Any way I prefer the @Jitendra Pancholi solution, which makes @Maarten two statements in one with the `??` operator.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit old but just in case it helps anyone.

@Matt I guess the `DefaultIFEmpty()` method should work for you just in case you pass a default value for the column that you are applying `Sum` onto. This method has some overloads which you might want to check and I suggest type-casting if overloads do not support your requirement.

```
 (query).DefaultIfEmpty(0)
```

Comment: It helped me. This is a great way to go.

Comment: It helps and sends only one query to the db, but a MOST ugly one ! Without DefaultIfEmpty it is just a simple SELECT statement, whereas with  DefaultIfEmpty the generated query uses 4 SELECTs. Instead checking in the db if there are any request, it should be possible to test in the C# client to test if the query has returned any records.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick (you may have to remove one of the conditions if either `Quantity` or `Price` are not nullable):

```
var cafeSales = db.InvoiceLines
    .Where(x =>
        x.UserId == user.UserId &&
        x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
        x.DateCharged <= dateEnd &&
        x.Quantity != null &&
        x.Price != null);

double cafeSalesTotal = 0;

if (cafeSales.Any())
{
    cafeSalesTotal = cafeSales.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
join sim in ctx.EF.Collaterals on new { id = ini.cam.id, Type = 0 } equals new 
{ id = sim.CampaignId == null ? new Guid() : sim.CampaignId, sim.Type } 
into tempcoll
from sim in tempcoll.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

This solution works.Actually You need to use ternary operator to check the value and insert Guid if null in the second column and in the second table.and it will work.
"The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null" will be solved
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 var cafeSales = db.InvoiceLines
.Where(x =>
    x.UserId == user.UserId &&
    x.DateCharged >= dateStart &&
    x.DateCharged <= dateEnd)
.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);

double i;
if(cafeSales==null) ? i=0 : i=(double)cafeSales.First();
```

Comment: Sum(...) will not return an enumerable, so calling a First() on the result of a Sum(...) will turn into a compile-time-error.

Comment: does it make any sense? :o if(cafeSales==null) ? i=0 : i=(double)cafeSales.First();

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above didn't work for me. My problem was similar. I was sure that no rows were being returned but Sum behaves in some strange way. So I decided to add a check just before calling the lambda expression where I check for count property of rows returned by the lambda. If it is greater than zero, then I call the sum expression. That worked for me.

Comment: TimeSheetRepository.GetAll().Where(t => t.UserID == theUserId).
                      Where(t => t.Date >= startDate).Where(t => t.Date <= endDate).Sum(t => t.Hours);

Comment: I had to check if there is a count like this TimeSheetRepository.GetAll().Where(t => t.UserID == theUserId).
                  Where(t => t.Date >= startDate).Where(t => t.Date <= endDate).Count() > 0   Calling the .Sum for the hours which is a decimal always resulted in the above error when no rows were present in the resultset

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.0, Nullable has a "GetValueOrDefault()" method.
So if you cast the query to Nullable, then you can end up with the correct Type when complete.
This method will also generate the correct single SQL SELECT SUM query and is faster than other solutions that return the entire recordset to later sum via linq

```
decimal result = ((decimal?)query.Where(w => w.Customer =="ABC").Sum(s =>  (decimal?)s.Amount)).GetValueOrDefault();
```