# check whether LINQ query returns rows

Tags: c#, linq, webmethod

I need to check whether a query returns rows and if it does, change it to a string, but if it doesn't, return "In Progress". I thought the below code would work but this is always true:

```
if (System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(columns) == 0)<--- always true but it shouldn't be
```

And when there isn't a row returned to columns I get the following error in my jQuery Ajax:
"The cast to value type \u0027Int32\u0027 failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type\u0027s generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Here's my WebMethod:

```
using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
    {
        var thisId = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projectID && x.StatusID == statusID).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
        var columns = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs
            .Where(x => x.BreadCrumbID == thisId)
            .Select(x => x.CreateDateTime)
            .ToList();

        if (System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(columns) == 0)
        {
            var formattedList = columns
                .Select(d => null != d
                    ? d.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
                    : string.Empty) // this is just one example to handle null
                .ToList();

            return formattedList;<-- return this if there is a BreadCrumbID (columns would have a row)
        }
        else
        {
            return "In Progress";<--- there was no BreadCrumbID (columns would have 0 rows)
        }

    }
```

Comment: have you tried `if(!columns.Any()) { ... }`

Comment: Actually as someone else pointed out, his condition is backwards. It should be columns.Any(), you had it right the first time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first check for `Count == 0`, doesn't sound right, I guess you need the opposite check. You should use `Any` or `Count() > 0` check, Like:

```
if (columns.Any()) //Or columns.Count() > 0
{
    var formattedList = columns
        .Select(d => null != d
            ? d.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
            : string.Empty) // this is just one example to handle null
        .ToList();

    return formattedList;<-- return this if there is a BreadCrumbID (columns would have a row)
}
else
{
    return "In Progress";<--- there was no BreadCrumbID (columns would have 0 rows)
}
```

You have to convert your List to string, in order for your method to return a string.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks. But I'm still getting the error:"The cast to value type \u0027Int32\u0027 failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type\u0027s generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

I think it's because thisId doesn't return any rows. Should I submit a new question about that or do you know how I conditionally check if thisID is NULL.

Comment: @user1431633, sure you can post a new question about it, but I guess the problem has to do with the some of your column being value type, thus you can't compare them with `null`, they should be `Nullable<T>` or `DateTime?`. For more details see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Any()`

[MSDN Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong. Count must be greater than zero

Answer (score 1):

You only needs to ckeck `.Count() > 0`

```
if (columns.Count() > 0)
        {
            var formattedList = columns
                .Select(d => null != d
                    ? d.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
                    : string.Empty) // this is just one example to handle null
                .ToList();

            return formattedList;<-- return this if there is a BreadCrumbID (columns would have a row)
        }
        else
        {
            return "In Progress";<--- there was no BreadCrumbID (columns would have 0 rows)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.Any()` method provided by `List<T>`:

```
If (columns.Any())
{
    // do your bidding
} else {
    // in progress code
}
```

Also your method has two different return signatures. That won't compile. You can't return a List or a string, unless the return type is object (not recommended).

I suggest to return a null list and check if it's null in your UI layer and then display the appropriate string or date values, since they end up as strings in the UI anyway.