# Have lambda return 0 if count is null

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lambda

Struggling to get my count correct. I believe I am close but I need it to return 0 if there are no records in the database. The compiler doesnt like what I have now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
var count = (_db.cart.Where(c => c.UserId == id)
            .Select(c => (int) c.Quantity)).ToList().Count() ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the null coalesce.

```
var count = _db.cart.Count(c => c.UserId == id);  // get record count
```

If you're actually trying to get a sum:

```
var total = _db.cart.Where(c => c.UserId == id)
                    .Select(c => (int?)c.Quantity)
                    .Sum() ?? 0;                  // get total
```

---

FYI, regarding the code you originally posted...

You wouldn't want to call `ToList().Count()`, because calling `ToList()` will execute your query and pull back data. You'll end pulling back a list of quantities and performing the count locally, instead of generating an SQL statement that simply performs the count and returns a single number.

Comment: What i there are no records in the database?

Comment: Shorter: var count = _db.cart.Count(c => c.UserId == id);

Comment: How does that query know to count the quantity field? isnt that just counting records?

Comment: No worries. Yeah each row if its there could have a quantity. Need to total up all the quantities while checking for null (if needed)

Comment: Dont think so. Its code first so Ill have to see what its building. Thanks

Comment: Actually it didnt work on null. it bombed and quantity is set to not null in sql

Comment: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: Thank You. This if check also did it for me if (!(_db.cart.Any(c => c.UserId == id)))

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Sum`, not `Count`

```
var totalQuantity = _db.cart.Where(c => c.UserId == id)
                            .Select(c => c.Quantity)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                            .Sum();
```

Comment: No need to check for null than?

Comment: Code actually did not work. Field is set to not null in sql but still bombs on null. Your second query is giving me left opperand of the ?? should be a reg or nullable type

Comment: if (_db.cart == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return _db.cart.Where(c => c.UserId == id)
                    .Select(c => c.Quantity)
                    .Sum();
            }

Comment: That code gives me "Additional information: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Comment: @osiris355 - ahh - that issue. I had forgotten about that.  I'll update. There's a good explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var count=_db.cart.where(c=>c.Userid==id).Count();
```