# Excluding NULL values when using SUM() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use `SUM()` to total all the entries in a column and then convert the number to an `int`.

I am running into a problem in the conversion because some of the entries are NULL. I tried to exclude them using a `!= null` in a `WHERE()` clause but I am still getting the same error

> The cast to value type `Int32` failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must
>   use a nullable type.

Here is my LINQ query, can someone point out what I am missing in order to properly exclude nulls?

```
TotalLiftings = db.Query<Transaction>().
    Where(tr => tr.TerminalId == TerminalUserData.ID && 
        tr.ProductId == t.ProductId && 
        tr.TransactionDate == t.InventoryDate &&
        tr.NetGallons != null).
Select(tr => tr.NetGallons).
Sum();
```

Comment: What is the type of the `NetGallons`?

Comment: Have you tried NetGallons.HasValue instead?  I am assuming NetGallons is nullable

Comment: Are you sure that the null is coming from the sum statement and not the where? I would say you should probably start off the where with checking the tr.TerminalId and tr.ProductId, transactionDate, etc. to make sure none of them are null before any other logic.

Comment: @Taugenichts I know there is data in the system but I did not think that the whole statement might just not return anything. I will investigate the `WHERE()` to see if that is where the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311

Comment: Another concern would be how do you know that TerminalUserData and t are not null? Those would definitely cause some problems if they were null...

Comment: @Taugenichts I have tested for and confirmed that `TerminalUserData` and `t` are not null. I am right now testing out the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast to a `nullable` `int`. The error is occuring because you are trying to sum no records and the result of that is `null`, but an `int` cant be `null`

```
.Select(tr => tr.NetGallons).Cast<int?>().Sum(),
```

or

```
  .Select(tr => (int?)tr.NetGallons).Sum(),
```

Comment: But he filtered and selected datas where `tr.NetGallons != null`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, the Sum of zero records is a null value. tr.NetGallons is an `int`, so the `Sum` method has to return an `int`. A null value cant be assigned to an int, so it throws an exception. An int can be compared against a null value, but it will always be true