# null issue during usage of count and sum LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, count, sum

I have three tables and they are linked like

```
grandparent -> parent -> child 

categoryType - > Categories - > Menus
```

when I try to run following

```
return categoryTypes.Select(x =>
                     new CategoryTypeIndexModel
                     {
                         Id = x.Id,
                         Name = x.Name,
                         Categories = x.Categories.Count,
                         Items = x.Categories.Sum(m => m.Menus.Count())
                     });
```

I get

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: `x.Categories.Sum(m => (int?) m.Menus.Count())`

Comment: Items = x.Categories.Where(m => m.Menus != null && m.Any()).Any() ? x.Categories.Where(m => m.Menus != null && m.Any()).Sum(m => m.Menus.Count()) : 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to count something that isn't there when Categories is null. 
I believe what Habib recommend would technically work but you would still have to account for a null value after the fact. 
I think the better solution would be to account for it in your linq directly by looking for null and providing a default

```
return categoryTypes.Select(x => new CategoryTypeIndexModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Categories = (x.Categories == null) ? 0 : x.Categories.Count,
        Items = (x.Categories == null) ? 0 : x.Categories.Sum(m => m.Menus.Count())
    });
```

If Menus could ever be null you would also need to account for that in a similar fashion

Comment: When I tried Habib’s solution, it says

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate 

and when I tried yours it gave following error after running

Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Repository.edmx.Category, Repository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: I see checking for null like i mentioned wont work in EF unless you enumerate the collection first but that gets more complicated with lazy loading etc. In this case Habib's solution is the correct one but the error you get leads me to think CategoryTypeIndexModel.Categories is a string type? If so change that to a nullable int

Comment: Categories is a table, not a field ….i converted coming result to IEnumerable first and then manipulated andit worked…thanks for help