# Error: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I had a problem with

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

I have looked up for the answer that will fix the issue that i have, but couldn't find the similar case.

I am trying to find out the `max` transaction id in the `tblTransactions` from the `account id` as input. If the account doesn't have any transactions,it will cause the error. The relationship between those two tables as **tblTransaction. accountId = tblAccount.Id**

my Controller:

```
//GET: Balance

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string useracc = (string)Session["AccountNumber"];

        var accountInstance = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(w => w.AccountNumber.ToString() == useracc);


        List<Transaction> AccountTransactions = db.Transactions.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id&&w.IsCancelled ==false).Select(w => w).OrderByDescending(w => w.Date).ToList();

            var accountStatement = AccountTransactions.Where(w => w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015).OrderByDescending(w => w.Date).ToList();

            var lastTransactionId = db.Transactions.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id && w.IsCancelled == false && w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015).Max(t => t.Id);

            var needDueDate = db.SystemInvoices.Where(s => s.Id == lastTransactionId).Select(s => s.DueDate).FirstOrDefault();



            List<customBalanceInfoItem> currCustomBalance = new List<customBalanceInfoItem>();

            customBalanceInfoItem displayItem = new customBalanceInfoItem();

            displayItem.AccountNumber = accountInstance.AccountNumber;
            displayItem.DueDate = needDueDate;

            currCustomBalance.Add(displayItem);
            return View(currCustomBalance);
        }
```

the error happened on the var lastTransactionId.

Comment: what does the last `db.Transactions.Where( ... )` evaluates to?

Comment: I am trying to get the due date of invoice for account. But for some accounts  which haven't got invoices yet. when i use those accounts run will cause the error, because in the transactions table couldn't find any accountId. I will list full controller for my balance page with due date.

Comment: just add a check to see if the evaluation is `null` and if not call `max` on it. Displaying an error message for invalid accounts is more proper that to just shadow it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify it using `DefaultIfEmpty()`, check [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/defaultifempty)

Modified Query

```
var lastTransactionId = db.Transactions.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id && w.IsCancelled == false && w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015)
                                       .Select(t=>t.Id)
                                       .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                                       .Max()
```

You can define the value need to returned, if the collection is empty, like I have made it -1, else it will be default value

Comment: I added DefaultIfEmpty(-1), but still query under red line before DefaultIfEmpty(-1).

Comment: Add ToList() before it this is a call on List type and you are doing it on IEnumerable type,check edited version

Comment: Sorry , tried still not working ,query under red line before ToList().DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Max(t => t.Id)

Comment: Post the exact error message provided by Red line, that's a compilation issue

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1929 'List<Transaction>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty<int>(IQueryable<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>' CustomerPortal

Comment: Check the modified version, tested on my system, this would surely work, you will get -1 if it is empty or the Max is selected

Comment: Thanks , it works finally. Sorry dont have enough reputation to vote :)

Comment: That's fine, good that it worked :), accept this as answer please

Answer (score -2):

try adding first or default which prevents null exception

```
var lastTransactionId = db.Transactions.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id && w.IsCancelled == false && w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015).Max(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But FirstOrDefault() seems cannot apply at the end.

Comment: This is failing at Max itself, so FirstOrDefault will not help

Comment: Syntax error. `Max()` already returns a value. Therefore, `FirstOrDefault()` method will not exist on your returned type.