# Using LINQ Expressions to Multiple Left Join and use ISNULL Functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm building a Step Tracking web app at work. I'm working with the latest EF Core. There are three tables I'm interacting with:

1. wg: WellnessGroup (WellnessGroupId, Name)
2. wgu: WellnessGroupUser (Look up table: WellnessGroupId, EmployeeId)
3. wsl: WellnessStepsLog (EmployeeId, StepCount)

What I want is to get all of the WellnessGroups and the total step amount for that group. If there are no steps attached to that group yet, I would like for the NULL value to be 0. I have this SQL statement which gives me the desired data:

```
SELECT wg.Name, SUM(ISNULL(wsl.StepCount, 0)) AS steps
FROM dbo.WellnessGroup AS wg
LEFT JOIN dbo.WellnessGroupUser AS wgu
ON wgu.WellnessGroupId = wg.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.WellnessStepsLog AS wsl
ON wsl.EmployeeId = wgu.AzureAdUserId
GROUP BY wg.Name
ORDER BY steps DESC;
```

And I have managed to throw 2 LINQ expressions together on my controller which is giving me only the WellnessGroups that have steps associated with them and is not giving me the WellnessGroup data if there are no steps:

```
 var query = _dbContext.WellnessGroupUser
                    .Include(x => x.WellnessGroup)
                .Join(_dbContext.WellnessStepsLog, group => 
                group.AzureAdUserId, steps => steps.EmployeeId,
                    (group, steps) => new
                    {
                        Steps = steps.StepCount,
                        Date = steps.TrackedDate,
                        Group = group.WellnessGroup.Name

                    }).Where(x => x.Date >= yearToDate).Where(x => x.Date <= endDate);

 var stepsByGroup = query
                .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    Group = s.Key,
                    Date = s.Max(x => x.Date),
                    Steps = s.Sum(x => x.Steps)
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to query all WellnessGroups and build the sum inside as a second subquery. Like this:

```
var query =
    db.WellnessGroup.Select(wg => new {
        wg.WellnessGroupId,
        sum = (int?) wg.WellnessGroupUser
                       .Sum(wgu => wgu.Employee.WellnessStepsLog.Sum(wsl => wsl.StepCount))
    });
```

Note, that the cast to (int?) is important. Otherwise sum is assumed to be int, which causes an InvalidOperationException if there is no sum for a row.

Another way is to build all the sums first. And then do the outer join with the WellnessGroups:

```
// sum up all stepcounts
var q1 =
    from wgu in db.WellnessGroupUser
    from wsl in db.WellnessStepsLog
    where wgu.EmployeeId == wsl.EmployeeId
    group wsl.StepCount by wgu.WellnessGroupId
    into g
    select new {WellnessGroupId = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum()};

// join with all WellnessGroups
var q2 =
    from wg in db.WellnessGroup
    join s in q1 on wg.WellnessGroupId equals s.WellnessGroupId into sj
    from sum in sj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {wg, sum = (int?) sum.Sum};
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since the OP later asked in the comments how to group by more then one field. Here is an example which groups by `WellnessGroup.WellnessGroupId` and the month of `WellnessStepsLog.TrackedDate`. There can be more then one field in `GroupBy` by placing them in a `new { ... }`. So the first query creates a line per possible WellnessGroup / Month combination. The second query performs the outer join with WellnessGroup just as before:

```
var q1 =
    from wgu in db.WellnessGroupUser
    from wsl in db.WellnessStepsLog
    where wgu.EmployeeId == wsl.EmployeeId
    group wsl.StepCount by new { wgu.WellnessGroupId, wsl.TrackedDate.Month }
    into g
    select new {g.Key.WellnessGroupId, g.Key.Month, Sum = g.Sum()};

// join with all WellnessGroups
var q2 =
    from wg in db.WellnessGroup
    join s in q1 on wg.WellnessGroupId equals s.WellnessGroupId into sj
    from sum in sj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {wg.WellnessGroupId, Month = (int?) sum.Month, Sum = (int?) sum.Sum};
```

Comment: Note that in LINQ to SQL (and I assume EF) the conversion to `int?` is automatic because of the possibility of `null` in SQL values.

Comment: @NetMage I thought that too. But in this example it did not work. I tried it. If you remove only the "(int?)" this exception happens: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'"

Comment: @NetMage: it seems you can't always trust the compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null

Comment: Ah - I wasn't using `Sum()`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the straightforward solution.

Comment: @nharrer if I were to also group all of the results by the WellnessStepsLog.TrackedDate, how I would I go about doing that? So I could see all of the WellnessGroups, their Steps, and IF they have Steps, the TrackedDate.Month in which they were tracked.

Comment: @Joe added another example which also groups by month.

Comment: @nharrer  I appreciate that, thank you. I noticed with the above query, I'm getting the groups and their corresponding steps grouped-by month which is what I want. However, now I'm multiple objects representing individual step counts per group per month: 

`{
"name": "IT",
"month": "January",
"steps": 35000
},
{
"name": "IT",
"month": "January",
"steps": 10000
},
{
"name": "IT",
"month": "January",
"steps": 80000
},`

What I want is just a single object per group per month. So:
`{
"name": "IT",
"month": "January",
"steps": 125000
}`