# The cast to value type ‘Int32’ failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing an issue here with this query here where i am getting this particular error:

Error:

```
The cast to value type ‘Int32’ failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type’s generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

The query itself is fairly simple:

```
prevMeasurementResults = context.vwInspections_ReadGrid_Web.Where(x => x.TaskTemplateID == Model.TaskTemplateID && x.TaskGroupID == (int?)Model.TaskGroupID && x.MeasurementResult != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MeasurementTypeUnitName)).ToList();
```

Both end of the `TaskTemplateID` is actually `int?` here.

What I have tried so far is:

1. Found an answer here in SO:
   [link to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864311/the-cast-to-value-type-int32-failed-because-the-materialized-value-is-null)1. But i couldnt implement on my query.
2. Changed my query to this to check for the null first before even starting to compare because thats what i read somewhere.

```
prevMeasurementResults = (from item in context.vwInspections_ReadGrid_Web
        where item.TaskTemplateID == (Model.TaskTemplateID == null ? item.TaskTemplateID : 
                                     Model.TaskTemplateID.Value)
                                      && item.MeasurementResult != null
                                      && item.WorkOrderTaskID <= Model.WorkOrderTaskID
                                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.MeasurementTypeUnitName)
                                     select item).ToList();
```

I am still getting the same error.

Some might mention that boolean method `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` cannot be translated to SQL here. But i did change that to actual C# `(item.MeasurementTypeUnitName != null || item.MeasurementTypeUnitName.Trim() != string.Empty)`. So thats not a problem.

No matter what i have tried I still get that error.
I am using ASP.NET Framework MVC if that matters. Its not ASP.NET Core.

Thank you for the help in Advance guys!

Comment: Check your DBModel properties whether which one implements `int` type but the DB table column was `int` with nullable type. If it does exist, then you need to change that property to be nullable type.

Comment: @YongShun i already did that, except for the one that i have explicitly casted `int?` they are all nullable types i have checked this 10 times. I even checked the dbSchema for any differences, non there as well. i have refreshed the view from EF as well.

Comment: The simplest way to diagnose is to remove/add the query part by part to minimize the scope of error. If you have removed all the queries (filter condition) and encounter the same issue, that means the issue in on your entity model. Since you not share the entity model and table schema here, it is hard to help you to identify the issue.

Comment: sure. I will try that.